# pip install nltk fails when instilling older version

Tags: python, pip

I've been trying to install an older version(2.0bp) of NLTK by using pip install to use some old scripts for natural language parsing.

I simply tried to use the command below as usual.

```
pip install nltk==2.0b9
```

It fails with an error.

```
Collecting nltk==2.0b9
Using cached nltk-2.0b9.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-build-uEdW6G/nltk/setup.py'

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-uEdW6G/nltk/
```

As suggested other posts on StackOverflow, I tried the commands but the installation still fails.

```
pip install --upgrade setup tools
```

I've used Python2.7 on pyenv, and pip itself is on 9.0.1.
Can you give me any suggestions to try?

Comment: What is the version of pip (`pip --version`), of Python (`python --version`)? To update pip and setuptools, the [recommended command](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#requirements-for-installing-packages) is `pip install -U pip setuptools`. It may also help if you state why you would install an ancient version of nltk.

Comment: Try `pip install nltk==2.0b9 --no-cache-dir`

Comment: @PierredeBuyl pip 9.0.1 is installed and python is Python 2.7.12 :: Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit). I tried the pip install command you mentioned but it still doesn't solve the problem. I've been trying to use a discourse parser provided the url below. http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~weifeng/software.html The README says nltk2.0b9 is needed and newer versions don't work because of the change the way to parse a tree.

Comment: @hoefling Trying --no-cache-dir option didn't help sadly.

Comment: SOLVED: I changed anaconda version to anaconda-2.0.0, which is with nlt==2.0.4. But I still don't understand the reason why pip install nltk==2.0b9 didn't work.

Comment: First thing: using anaconda, you probably have a recent enough pip and setuptools and should use conda itself to update those. With anaconda, `conda install` is the primary resource for installing anaconda-provided packages. Then, "2.0b9" is a beta release (as indicated by the "b9") and might suffer from a configuration problem for the install. The setup.py file is not located at the root of the downloaded archive file, I suppose that creates the problem.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl 's advice helped me. thanks.